# Unable to redirect the output of a background process

Tags: linux, bash, sockets

The below command basically starts a software which enagages a socket connection

```
./ctest.sh start tof as tof-${ID} with config ${ID}/test.properties-${ID}.properties version 1.15.0 > ${TOF_HOME}/nohup_run_${ID}.log 2>&1 &
```

When i run the above command in a loop, it actaully is not starting for all elements in loop, EACH ELEMENT HAS A SEPARATE CONNECTION ACTUALLY

ex :

```
 for ID in loym loyx lloy
 do
     ./ctest.sh start tof as tof-${ID} with config ${ID}/test.properties-${ID}.properties version 1.15.0 > ${TOF_HOME}/nohup_run_${ID}.log 2>&1
     &
sleep 2
 done
```

but when i do below its starting for everything in loop , but i need aseparate log file

```
 for i in loym loyx lloy
 do
     nohup ./ctest.sh start tof as tof-${ID} with config ${ID}/tof.properties-${ID}.properties version 1.15.0 &
 sleep 2 
 done
```

I am unable to understand why the redirection to log file is not working here

Comment: where is the variable 'i' used? Should it be ID?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz oh sorry , yeah it’s ID

Comment: does it work with that change?

Comment: What "redirection to log file"? There's no redirection anywhere in your second script.

Comment: Can you generate a [mcve] that people who don't have your `ctest.sh`, and properties files can run to see the problem (and validate their solutions)?

Comment: Nope , the correction  doesn’t work , redirection is the issue here , without nohup, I would like to have a separate log files( err and stdout data) per each ID separately , and this is not being done

Comment: Fine, but where's your code that *should* do that? You only have a redirection in the first script and not the second. If there's no redirection, then there's nothing that *should* be working, so I'm not clear on what the problem is.

Comment: Yes , I meant that when I removed the redirection script is working file as whole output goes to nohup.out

Comment: Right, that's how `nohup` is defined to work in its documentation. Again, what's the problem?

Comment: Can’t I have separate log files per each ID , with this alll the data is pushed to nohup and grep the ID related data would be difficult

Comment: (BTW, in general, you *shouldn't* use `nohup` -- it does absolutely nothing that you couldn't do with native bash; see in particular the `disown` builtin).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163434/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-learningcpp).